# Structuring many update statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, structure

I'm using SQL Server. I'm also relatively new to writing SQL... in a strong way. It's mostly self-taught, so I'm probably missing key ideas in terms of proper format.

I've a table called 'SiteResources' and a table called 'ResourceKeys'. SiteResources has an integer that corresponds to the placement of a string ('siteid') and a 'resourceid' which is an integer id that corresponds to 'resourceid' in ResourceKeys. ResourceKeys also contains a string for each key it contains ('resourcemessage'). Basically, these two tables are responsible for representing how strings are stored and displayed on a web page.

The best way to consistently update these two tables, is what? Let's say I have 5000 rows in SiteResources and 1000 rows in ResourceKeys. I could have an excel sheet, or a small program, which generates 5000 singular update statements, like:

```
update SiteResources set resoruceid = 0 
WHERE siteid IS NULL AND resourceid IN (select resourceid 
from ResourceKeys where resourcemessage LIKE 'FooBar')
```

I could have thousands of those singular update statements, with FooBar representing each string in the database I might want to change at once, but isn't there a cleaner way to write such a massive number of update statements? From what I understand, I should be wrapping all of my statements in begin/end/go too, just in-case of failure - which leads me to believe there is a more systematic way of writing these update statements? Is my hunch correct? Or is the way I'm going about this correct / ideal? I could change the structure of my tables, I suppose, or the structure of how I store data - that might simplify things - but let's just say I can't do that, in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you just need to update everything in table SiteResources with empty parameter 'placement of a string'. If so, here is the code:

```
UPDATE a 
SET resourceid = 0 
FROM SiteResources a
WHERE EXISTS (select * from ResourceKeys b where a.resourceid = b.resourceid) 
AND a.siteid IS NULL
```

For some specific things like 'FooBar'-rows you can add it like this:

```
UPDATE a 
SET resourceid = 0 
FROM SiteResources a
WHERE EXISTS (select * from ResourceKeys b where a.resourceid = b.resourceid and b.resourcemessage IN ('FooBar', 'FooBar2', 'FooBar3', ...)) 
AND a.siteid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood the question correctly. You'd like to update `resourceid` to 0 if the `resourcemessage` corresponds to a list of strings ? If so, you can build your query like this.

```
UPDATE r 
SET resourceid = 0 
FROM SiteResources r
JOIN ResourceKeys k ON r.resourceid = k.resourceid
WHERE k.resourcemessage IN ('FooBar', ...)
AND r.siteid IS NULL;
```

This is using an extended `UPDATE` syntax in transact-sql allowing you to use a `JOIN` in the UPDATE statement. But maybe it's not exactly what you want ? Why do you use the LIKE operator in your query, without wildcard (`%`) ?

Comment: This works on your interpretation of what I mean - but I guess I was bad at explaining, but it's okay though, this was helpful. I don't necessarily want to set anything to zero, I was just using zero as a dummy value. The design of the table is to store messages or html code for a site that can be changed dynamically through SQL updates. As for why I'm using like without a wildcard, LIKE, I believe, will ignore spaces even without a wildcard, as opposed to =. I use it just in-case of whitespace.

Comment: the = comparison operator trims automatically spaces at its right. `'hello' = 'hello     '` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

With table-valued parameters, you can pass a table from your client app to the SQL batch that your app submits for execution. You can use this to pass a list of all the strings you need to update to a single `UPDATE` that updates all rows at once.

That way you don't have to worry about all of your concerns: the number of updates, transactional atomicitty, error handling. As a bonus, performance will be improved.

I recommend that you do a bit of research what TVPs are and how they are used.